# Eigenvalue distribution of a Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I apologize in advance if question seems bit vague. But I was wondering if we have two positive definite matrices, A, and B, with a graph of their eigenvalues, sorted as per magnitude. (see below for graph of two positive definite matrices that I was working on which prompted the question)
[image: eigen value plot]

**Then given the distribution shape, what possible comments can be made regarding the possible solutions of Ax = b, and Bx = b?** specifically regarding the jumps in orange matrix plot.

Comment: For some particular matrices you can find some relationships, such as in Gaussian Orthogonal Ensembles, as explained in https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/07/30/goe-eigenvalues/

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda_{min}(A)$ and $\lambda_{max}(A)$ are the least and greatest eigenvalues of the positive definite matrix $A$, and similarly for $B$, then all you can say is
$$ \max\left( \frac{\|b\|}{\lambda_{max}(A)}, \frac{\|b\|}{\lambda_{max}(B)}\right) \le \|x\|
\le \min\left( \frac{\|b\|}{\lambda_{min}(A)}, \frac{\|b\|}{\lambda_{min}(B)}\right)
$$
All other details of the distributions are irrelevant.